# Created Postgresql Views don't work in Npgsql

Tags: postgresql, npgsql

I would like to call the Postgresql Views with NpgsqlCommand but for some reason it doesn't work? Can you help me here and is it even possible with Npgsql?

Here is the call from the NpgsqlCommand:

```
  using (var command = new NpgsqlCommand("SELECT * FROM probandsearchresultsqlview", connection))
  {
    connection.Open();
     using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader())
     {
       if (!reader.HasRows)
       return null;
      ......
```

And here is the created PostgreSQL View:

```
CREATE VIEW probandsearchresultsqlview AS 
 SELECT probands.pid,probands.first_name,probands.last_name FROM probands;
```

After creating the view the call SELECT * FROM probandsearchresultsqlview in pgAdmin works but not in Npgsql.

Comment: what is the error message?

Comment: the view can't have been created as it is. There is a faulty coma just before the `from` clause

Comment: that's not the reason. I did it wrong in stackoverflow copy paste ;-)

Comment: Please post the complete exception you're getting, including the stack trace.